# Octave. dlmread: unable to open file 'myfile.txt'

Tags: io, octave

I have a txt file with data in form: 2104,3,399900 i_e int1,int2,int3 I have 50 rows in the same format.

Now I can want to put the data into variable, say, a.

I am using the the command :

```
a = csvread('ex1data2.txt'); 
%I have tried a = dlmread('ex1data2.txt'); it too does't work
```

it produces an error :

**error: dlmread: unable to open file 'ex1data2.txt'.**

I have added the path of the directory that have file  to the octave search paths.
How can I read the text file?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have read access to `myfile.txt` and that it's located in the same directory of your Octave script. The command you're typing is correct and should work properly.

Comment: [link](https://i.imgur.com/jij6xbl.png)
Yes, the script I'm calling is 'ex1_multi.m' and the text file being used is 'ex1data2.txt'.

Comment: Then you should change your command to `a = csvread('ex1data2.txt');`. It's no wonder it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I am calling `a = csvread('ex1data2.txt');`. I gave the example just for the sake of simplicity.